# Running tests using DataProvider in a particular flow

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a `DataProvider` which reads a CSV file like below

```
john|26|mba
claire|33|bbl
knight|29|mpa
```

Now I have three `classes` which has one `@Test` each

Classes Names are

```
NameReader.java
ProcessStudent.java
ValidateDatabase.java
```

My `NameReader.java` has one `@Test` method which gets the input from the aforementioned data provider. So in this case if I execute just the `NameReader.java` it will run 3 times since there are three rows

But the problem is I want `NameReader.Java` to accept 1st row from the data provider and then run `ProcessStudent.java` and then run `ValidateDatabase.java`. This flow should happen for remaining two rows from the `DataProvider` as well.

But if I specify my `testng.xml` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="1" name="Test" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.java.testng.NameReader"/>
      <class name="com.java.testng.ProcessStudent"/>
      <class name="com.java.testng.ValidateDatabase"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

It runs the `@Test` inside `NameReader.java` 3 times first and then moves on to the `@Test` inside `ProcessStudent.java` and then to the `@Test` inside `ValidateDatabase.java`.

Please remember I don't need to use the aforementioned `DataProvider` in either `ProcessStudent.java` or `ValidateDatabase.java`

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Call ProcessStudent and ValidateDatabase test methods from NameReader test method. Had to declare ProcessStudent and ValidateDatabase test methods as static methods.

```
public class NameReader {

@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void testNameReader(String str1, String str2) {

    System.out.println("data set = "+str1+"  "+str2);
    System.out.println("NameReader ends");

    ProcessStudent.testClassB();
    ValidateDatabase.testClassC();
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData(){
//data set here
 }
```